# External repository moved from Sourceforge (SVN) to GitHub, now what?

Tags: git, svn

We've been getting the head revision of the JEDI Code library for a while, we only use it a tiny bit so never have bothered to manage which version we're getting.  The problem is they appear to be totally untethered from SVN now and we'd been including it in our repository as an external and now my build server it kaput.

The obvious thing to do would be to just download zip and make a new repository on my SVN server and use that instead, updating when I feel like it.  But is there a better solution? We use Tortoise SVN as an SVN client.

(BTW, it's pretty strange that the JCL changed to Git with the great integration in the Delphi IDE isn't it?)

Comment: No, it's not strange. Git is really a lot better than subversion and integration to IDE is not actually worth much in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome [apparently you can connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919069/using-svn-to-connect-to-a-git-repository) straight to github using SVN.

Now all they need is a redirect from sourceforge and the other broken links on the wiki!